# Logstash not streaming to SolR

Tags: solr, logstash

I've got the following log-flow:

`FileBeat -> Logstash -> SolR -> Banana`

and I know that filebeat is streaming to logstash successfully, since I can log the output to terminal. For some reason, the data is not being channelled into SolR for indexing... I'm using a the [solr_http](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-solr_http.html#plugins-outputs-solr_http) plugin, and the config looks like this:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
} 
output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
  solr_http { solr_url => "http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted" }
}
```

Is there something I have to configure in SolR?

Comment: I haven't used the solr output, but I'd look in the logstash and solr logs.

Comment: ...so far 2 things, the http payload was too large, but my latest issue is adding the event_timestamp field into the log

Answer (score 2):

It seems that a problem in the logstash-output-solr_http plugin. 
See the following issue:
https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-solr_http/issues/3

You can try to check is it exactly the problem just sending a call to the Solr API like here [How to optimize solr index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954358/how-to-optimize-solr-index).

I've used this one: https://github.com/mosuka/logstash-output-solr.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and for more that I searched on the internet I did not find a solution, what I had to do was configure apache flume with a morphilines sink, because this works in a more native way, in my concept logstash with output solr plugin does not work.

I hope it's your help